# How can I add a throws exception clause in my MainActivity class?

Tags: java, android, exception

So I'm trying to use BufferedReader to read in words from a txt file containing about 250k words. When I create a BufferedReader object and try to pass it a File, android studio tells me there is an unhandled exception (FileNotFoundException).  I solved this by wrapping it in a try catch statement however I was wondering if I could have added a throws FileNotFoundException clause next to my class declaration like i do sometimes when im writing a program outside of android (just java no android).

Eclipse highlights the error and when you click it it gives you the option to add throws clause. I searched for similar questions and i read that the analogous feature with IntelliJ is to hold mouse cursor over the underlined error and press alt + enter, it gives you the option to either wrap in try catch or add a throws clause. Im using android studio on a mac, not Intellij, and when i did this it didn't give me any such option. Am I using the correct shortcut for android studio/mac/Intellij?? Is it not allowing me to add a throws clause because it extends Activity already? Any help would be appreciated.

This doesn't work:
http://gyazo.com/e5d8d87f3030d8628bee403f4cbf37ce

What I get when i press alt+enter over the error:
http://gyazo.com/b89fc7f8f4c311f64f6fb2d98b68b96a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if I could have added a throws FileNotFoundException clause next to my class declaration

Classes do not throw exceptions. Methods throw exceptions. So, no, you cannot add `throws FileNotFoundException` to a class declaration.

Comment: ah yes, i got confused because i thought of mainactivity as analogous to Main method :/ so silly. thanks for the response, btw the commonsware android guide is amazing :)